# Spring - How to get subset of properties file without enumerating all required properties

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp, spring-properties

I am loading my properties file as following:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
class MyApp {
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

In the properties file, I have several database-related properties:

```
database.dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:${db-port:5432}/mydb
database.dataSource.x=...
database.dataSource.y=...
database.dataSource.z=...
```

Note:

- `${db-port}` should be replaced by either the value of property/environment variable `db-port` or 5432. In my case, I am defining the environment variable `db-port` when spawning the Tomcat container.
- All database-related properties are grouped under `database.` root. This is intentional, see below.

**I want to avoid that I have to enumerate/hardcode all possible database-related properties in my code.** Luckily, the database layer in use (Hikari) has the nice feature that I can pass all properties via a `java.util.Properties`. So, I want retrieve all defined properties under `database.*` and simply forward it to Hikari.

For this, I wrote the following utility:

```
@Component
public class PropertyFetcher
{
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    public Properties get(final String key) {
        final Properties p = new Properties();

        for (final PropertySource<?> s : environment.getPropertySources()) {
            if (s instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                for (final String k : ((EnumerablePropertySource) s).getPropertyNames()) {
                    if (k.startsWith(key) && k.length() > key.length()) {
                        p.put(k.substring(key.length()), s.getProperty(k));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Now, when calling `get("database.")`, I have all database-related properties as defined in the properties file. Great! But, the value for property `dataSource.url` is now

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:${db-port:5432}/mydb
```

instead of

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9876/mydb
```

So, for some reason, the `${db-port:5432}` is not resolved (yet?) when going via this route (`ConfigurableEnvironment`).

How can this be fixed? Or is there a better way to get all properties under a certain root without having to enumerate/hardcode them into the code?

Please note that in the default scenario, the `${db-port:5432}` in property `database.dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:${db-port:5432}/mydb` is correctly resolved. I tested this by defining the following member and logging it:

```
@Value("${database.dataSource.url}")
final String url; // holds jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9876/mydb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the property values from real environment only. Then only you will get actual or effective value of a property.

This will require a little change in your code.

change this line:

```
p.put(k.substring(key.length()), s.getProperty(k));
```

to this:

```
p.put(k.substring(key.length()), environment.getProperty(k));
```

Comment: Great, this fixed it! I already had the environment (`ConfigurableEnvironment`), so I just called `environment.getProperty(k)` and it works! Or should there be a good reason to inject `Environment` (not `ConfigurableEnvironment`) separately?

Comment: ConfigurableEnvironment extends Environment. So it is good to have only one injection. thanks for that point. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.